# Cross table of several columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table

I have this dataset called x for example:

| client_id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I then want to create another table, that calculates the number of times each column from a to c had 1, in combination of other columns having 1 too.

So the result would be this table:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| c | 1 | 2 | 1 |

So the first line of the second table would read like:
How many times there was only column a having a 1? it's once only.
How many times there was 1 in both a and b? it's only once.
How many times there was 1 in both a and c? it happened only once.

How can I do this easily in R? note that I only want to focus on when the column had 1.

Comment: I don't understand this logic, why is it that for "a" you want the count of rows where only a has a 1 (and all the other columns are 0), while for the combinations you want all the rows where both are 1 (but the other columns can be either)?

Comment: Maybe there is no instance where a meets a, except when we consider a alone. The thing is, I just want to find a good way to count the instances, whether combined or alone. So if there is another way to see this more clearly, I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `crossprod` to build the off-diagonal entries. For later referencing, this is sometimes called a co-occurrence matrix.

To create the diagonal, it's a bit more tricky: find rows that sums up to 1 and apply a column-wise sum.

```r
mat <- as.matrix(df[-1])
out <- crossprod(mat)  # Same as: t(mat) %*% mat
diag(out) <- colSums(mat[rowSums(mat) == 1, ])
out

#   a b c
# a 1 1 1
# b 1 0 2
# c 1 2 1
```